# How to change the rules for latexmk that biber is not run before pdflatex?

Tags: latexmk

I have settled with latexmk instead of the intrinsic order of commands within texstudio. This works very well. However, running makeindex and biber before pdflatex is not well advised in my case. Biber takes more than 100 secs to run and it will be run twice when I changed the bibliography and added new citations in the text. Therefore, I would like to change the rules that it is only run once. How to do that?

Kind regards
Bernhard

Comment: I don't think you can. If latexmk detects a change it will rerun the number of times it see fit. However, I do not understand why biber would need to run twice?

Comment: I do not either. Biber runs once after makeindex. Then multiple runs of pdflatex, then biber again, and at least two final runs of pdflatex.

Comment: You could just disable bibtex/biber and just run it manually. I have yet to start using biber. Is your bibliography very long? 100secs seems excessive

Comment: The OP changed both the .bib file and citations in the .tex file. Then latexmk does biber, pdflatex, biber, pdflatex, instead of the optimal pdflatex, biber, pdflatex. Under normal circumstances, the run of biber is quick, so the non-optimality is unimportant; but 100 sec is no longer quick.  Source files for both the biber and pdflatex changed, so both programs need to be run, and latexmk needs to choose which to run first. Its choice of biber first would be correct if no citations in the .tex changed. It would need reprogramming of latexmk to change this.

Comment: John, I filed a bug report at latex-mk's sourceforge web site, when I noted that  you are the programmer.

Comment: The bug report has never been dealt with. I wonder

Comment: This issue can be closed. Biber in the latest version is down to 19 secs, no need to change any rules in latexmk.